# Did the Wright brothers patent their Wing Warping method in Germany?

Tags: aviation-history, roll

I know that the Wright brothers patented their Wing Warping method for controlling the roll of a plane or glider in Great Britain, France, United States, Austria, Italy,... but **did they obtain a patent for it in Germany?**

This is the Austrian patent:

- [Orville and Wilbur Wright, “Austrian Patent No. 23174 – Flugmaschine”, Filed: 23 March, 1904, Beginning of patent term: 15 September, 1905, Issued: 26 February, 1906, 3 pages.](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/originalDocument?CC=AT&NR=23174B&KC=B&FT=D&ND=3&date=19060226&DB=EPODOC&locale=en_EP)

They have a German patent published in 1906 (see below) but I never found its content. I do not know what is written in it.

- Orville Wright und Wilbur Wright in Dayton, (V. St. A.)
  Patentschrift. Nr. 173378. Klasse 77h. Gruppe 7. Mitwagerechtem Kopfruder und senkrechtem Schwanzruder versehener Gleitflieger. Patentiert im Deutschen Reichevom 24. M rz 1904 ab. Ausgegeben den 16. Juli 1906. Berlin: Kaiserliches Patentamt, 1906, 4 pp., +illus.